# Alternative exponential symbol

Tags: symbols

I would like to create an exponential symbol that looks like an e scripted together with an x, slightly below, like the picture attached. Does it exist already? Ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here, I just overlay a `scriptscriptstyle x` near an `e`, and make sure I scale it to the current mathstyle.  I call it `\esubx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\esubxcore{\makebox{$e_{\mkern-3.4mu\raisebox{.6pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle x$}}$}}
\def\esubx{\scalerel*{\esubxcore}{e_{\scriptscriptstyle x}}}
\begin{document}
$xe/\esubx \quad \scriptstyle xe/\esubx \quad \scriptscriptstyle xe/\esubx$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one is rightly concerned that the symbol could be misinterpreted as an e with an x subscript, one could place the "x" in a sans font to help differentiate its appearance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\esubxcore{\makebox{$e_{\mkern-1.4mu\raisebox{.5pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathsf{x}$}}$}}
\def\esubx{\scalerel*{\esubxcore}{e_{\scriptscriptstyle x}}}
\begin{document}
$xe/\esubx \quad \scriptstyle xe/\esubx \quad \scriptscriptstyle xe/\esubx$
\end{document}
```

[image]